# Using the .Net regexp can I capture one unique sub-pattern and multiple repeating sub-patterns on the same line

Tags: .net, regex, pattern-matching, repeat

### Context

I have a line of text as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Pport xmlns="http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/PushPort/v12" xmlns:ns3="http://www.thalesgroup.com/rtti/PushPort/Forecasts/v2" ts="2016-06-16T02:04:51.6827805+01:00" version="12.0"><uR requestSource="Manu" updateOrigin="Trust"><TS rid="201606152851950" ssd="2016-06-15" uid="Y27259"><ns3:Location tpl="COLNE" wtd="23:55"><ns3:dep at="23:55" src="TRUST" srcInst="Manu"/><ns3:plat platsup="true">1</ns3:plat></ns3:Location><ns3:Location tpl="CHAFRSS" wta="23:58:30" wtd="23:58:30"><ns3:arr at="23:57" src="TRUST" srcInst="TGPS"/><ns3:dep at="23:57" src="TRUST" srcInst="TGPS"/></ns3:Location><ns3:Location tpl="GANNOWJ" wtp="00:06:30"><ns3:pass at="00:06" src="TD"/></ns3:Location><ns3:Location tpl="ACRNGTN" wtp="00:13:30"><ns3:pass at="00:13" src="TD"/><ns3:plat cisPlatsup="true" platsup="true">2</ns3:plat></ns3:Location><ns3:Location tpl="BLKBDJN" wtp="00:19:30"><ns3:pass at="00:19" src="TRUST" srcInst="Auto"/></ns3:Location><ns3:Location tpl="BLKB" wtp="00:20:30"><ns3:pass at="00:20" src="TD"/><ns3:plat cisPlatsup="true" conf="true" platsrc="A" platsup="true">4</ns3:plat></ns3:Location><ns3:Location tpl="LSTHJN" wtp="00:29"><ns3:pass at="00:30" src="TD"/></ns3:Location><ns3:Location tpl="FRNGTNC" wtp="00:35:30"><ns3:pass at="00:35" src="TD"/></ns3:Location><ns3:Location tpl="PRST" wta="00:38:30" wtd="00:44:30"><ns3:arr at="00:39" src="TD"/><ns3:dep at="00:46" src="TD"/><ns3:plat platsrc="A" platsup="true">1</ns3:plat></ns3:Location><ns3:Location tpl="PRSTNFJ" wtp="00:45:30"><ns3:pass et="00:47" src="Darwin"/></ns3:Location><ns3:Location tpl="KIRKMNJ" wtp="00:54:30"><ns3:pass at="00:58" src="TRUST" srcInst="Manu"/></ns3:Location><ns3:Location tpl="KIRKM51" wtp="00:57:30"><ns3:pass et="01:01" src="Darwin"/></ns3:Location><ns3:Location tpl="PLTNLFY" wtp="01:00:30"><ns3:pass at="01:05" src="TRUST" srcInst="Manu"/><ns3:plat cisPlatsup="true" platsup="true">1</ns3:plat></ns3:Location><ns3:Location tpl="LAYTCLX" wtp="01:03:30"><ns3:pass at="01:07" src="TRUST" srcInst="Manu"/></ns3:Location><ns3:Location tpl="BLCKPLN" wta="01:07" wtd="01:18"><ns3:arr at="01:10" src="TRUST" srcInst="Manu"/><ns3:dep at="01:18" src="TRUST" srcInst="Manu"/><ns3:plat platsup="true">2</ns3:plat></ns3:Location><ns3:Location tpl="BLCKNCS" wta="01:23"><ns3:arr at="01:21" src="TRUST" srcInst="TGPS"/></ns3:Location></TS></uR></Pport>
```

I'd like to capture all "tpl" values that have an associated "at" value. I do this currently using the follwing regexp pattern

> tpl="([A-Z]{4,})"[^<>]+><[^<>]+at="(\d{2}:\d{2})

This can be see here

[Regex Pattern](https://regex101.com/r/aJ3rZ3/1)

And I get 14 matches on that line.

### Problem

But I also want to capture the "rid" value and the "ssd" value that appear before any of the other matches on that line. I try to do it with this

> rid="(\d+)" ssd="(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}).+?tpl="([A-Z]{4,})"[^<>]+><[^<>]+at="(\d{2}:\d{2})

This captures the "rid" and the "ssd", but in doing so it loses the 13 other matches for the previous subpattern which I want alongside these two values

as seen here

[Regex Pattern2](https://regex101.com/r/dS2kT8/1)

Is it possible to capture all of the values I want with one regexp pattern?

Comment: Trying to use a regex on HTML and testing the regex at a site not supporting .NET syntax... Why not use an XML parser?

Comment: Is there a specific reason why your using regex? I would have thought using XPath, Linq, or xsl would have been more suited for this task.

Comment: Thank you for you observations. Although it uses the .NET regexp engine, I am working on Powershell at the moment and not on a Visual Studio System, so something like Linq might not work. But as both of you pointed it might be more worthwhile for me to explore manipulating with xpath, I guess. But I am still interested in understanding conceptually whether what I have asked for is possible and I am missing a trick with regexp.